# Firebase save Traffic use with setPersistenceEnabled

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`

As I understand it, The Firebase client will keep a local copy (on disk) of all data that the app has recently listened to.

this is my firebase node

`/users/userhash/privateTalk/messages/`

Example case

`/users/user01-hash/privateTalk/messages/push-hash/hello
/users/user01-hash/privateTalk/messages/push-hash/hi
/users/user01-hash/privateTalk/messages/push-hash/hey`

and i'm use AddChildEventListener

`FirebaseDB.instance().ChatDB.Child("users").Child("user01-hash").Child("privateTalk").Child("messages").AddChildEventListener(m_privateTalkListener);`

on disk "hi", "hello", "hey"

server "hi" , "hello", "hey", **"new msg 01", "new msg 02"**

I'm wondering if my App Oncreate, Firebase just download "new msg 01", "new msg 02" from server

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Persistence creates on on disk cache so that you can continue working with Firebase when your application closes or goes offline. So say you added a message, "offline-message", but could not connect to the internet? Firebase will store the write operation and the new message in its local cache. Firebase will treat that local reference as valid for functions as well. So if you had a "child-added" event listener, it would still fire when the child was added to your local copy. When your device re-establishes a connection with the database, it will make all of the stored transactions and update the stored values. The same thing would happen if the user closed the app before the database could sync: It will persist the changes and make the updates the next time the app opens and is connected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I posted a more detailed question again. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289308/firebase-can-i-get-only-messages-that-are-not-on-disk-from-the-server)